# Simple C++ code not giving correct results. Possibly because of float int comparison?

Tags: c++

I've written this simple piece of code to figure out a bug I faced in one part of a project.

Kindly find my code below:-

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 float x = 0;
 int c=30;
 while(c--){
    cout<<x<<endl;
    x += 0.1;
    if(x>1.00){ 
        cout<<"reset"<<x<<endl;
        x=0;
     }
 }

}
```

However instead of printing a steady stream like 0 -> 0.1 -> 0.2 -> ..... -> 0.8 -> 0.9 -> 1 -> 0.1, it print below:-

[image]

X resets back to zero when at 1 and not when x>1. I'm guessing it might be because x is float here and so x might not be purely 1.000000(so on) but might be something like 1.00000002 or something.

My question is if this assumption is right and also what can i do to rectify this and get the printed stuff as i need.  Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Copy-paste text as text into your question. That includes program output. And [never include that `<bits/stdc++.h>` header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Comment: A workaround: `if (x > 1.00001) ...`.

Comment: ooh damn thanks @Someprogrammerdude, wouldnt have known this otherwise

Comment: thanks @Damien , ill try this out

Comment: is it cool if i can delete this post since i know now its a duplicate?